# NPE in statement.executeQuery

Tags: java, sqlite, minecraft, bukkit

I have a problem with statement.executeQuery. Every time I call this I get a Null Pointer Exception and I don't really know what the problem is.

Here is the line on my GitHub Rep
[GitHub Rep](https://github.com/Xearoxde/Maven/blob/master/xConomy/src/main/java/de/xearox/xconomy/utility/Database.java#L95)

And here is the Stacktrace

> [21:16:53 INFO]: Xearox issued server command: /ecweb register Xearox 12345
>   org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'ecweb' in plugin xConomy v0.0.1
>           at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:641) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1162) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:997) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_79]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_79]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:44) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:715) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_79]
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           at de.xearox.xconomy.utility.Database.createNewPlayer(Database.java:95) ~[?:?]
>           at de.xearox.xconomy.XConomy.onCommand(XConomy.java:241) ~[?:?]
>           at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-5f38d38-18fbb24]
>           ... 15 more

The creating of the database table working fine.

Maybe you can help me out here I don't really know what I do wrong here :/

Thank You

Comment: Post code here, and not to your question but your query is incorrect: the *values* also need to be comma separated at `VALUES ('"+uuid+playerName+username+password+"');`

Comment: Use PreparedStatement instead of plain Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A null pointer exception means something is returning null. Add a null check

```
if(!sql == null){
    //Not null
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
}
else{//Its null do whatever}
```